# How to convert seconds (double) to QDateTime in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qdatetime

I have a number of seconds stored in a double format (but they are integer values if that's to be concerned). I would like to convert them to a `hh:mm:ss format` string. How to do that?

For example `double secs = 120;` would `be 00:02:00`.

Comment: What does the `secs` variable really contain? Are these seconds since beginning of the day or since 1.1.1970 which is Unix time (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?

Comment: this variable contains time interval expressed in seconds.

Comment: if it cant be a real number, why not `int` or even `long long`?

Comment: I am just storing it as double because of other functionalities. I Convert it to int.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a [`QTime`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#QTime) object by using its default constructor and then [add your seconds](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#addMSecs) to it:

```
double secs = 120;

QTime a(0,0,0);
a = a.addSecs(int(secs));
```

Comment: Same in here, I get empty string when converting time.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło You're right, I fixed it. The `QTime` is invalid when not initialized with `0,0,0` or any other actual time values. Answer edited

Comment: You might write `a = a.addSecs(int(secs));` too and do not involve second `QTime` object.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you convert seconds into hours, mins and seconds?

```
double secsDouble = 3666.0; // 1 hour, 1 min, 6 seconds.
int secs = (int)secsDouble;

int h = secs / 3600;
int m = ( secs % 3600 ) / 60;
int s = ( secs % 3600 ) % 60;

QTime t(h, m, s);
qDebug() << time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I could do this but I thought there is an automatic method.

Answer (score 0):

```
QTime time;
time = time.addSecs((int)secs);
qDebug() << time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: For some reason this procedure doesnt work. When I convert the time to string I get an empty string.

Comment: Same effect, empty string.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło Don't know why. I copy paste this code, and he work fine.

Comment: I had to declare time with default values like @Bowdzone explained

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło very strangely, by default, from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html , default values are the same.